# Validation in my CakePHP seems disabled

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm following the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/219/Blog) on CakePHP website, but validation doesn't work and I don't understand why, because I'm using the blog tutorial code.

I'll report directly from my files anyway...

MODEL

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Post';

    var $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Posts';

    function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }

    function view($id) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());

    }

    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW (add view)

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $form->create('Post');
echo $form->input('title');
echo $form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

When I reach the /posts/add page and then click to Save without any input text it doesn't reload with error; it inserts the empty data into db and then redirects me with the message "Your post has been saved".

Why doesn't validate itself? I've read into [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/443/validate) that it's not necessary to call `validate()`; `save()` is enough.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: I was naming the model files capitalizing them. So, I had a `Post.php` instead of a `post.php`.

CakePHP didn't find my models and so it was using its "generated" models.